# macOS Messages app: how can I undo the deletion of a conversation?

Tags: time-machine, messages

I deleted a conversation by mistake. Restoring ~/Library/Messages from Time Machine doesn’t undo the deletion. Something else must have to be restored. What?

I'm on macOS 10.15.5

Comment: See also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173641/85275

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Messages app Preferences, sign out.
2. Quit Messages.
3. From Time Machine

   - restore ~/Library/Messages/
   - restore ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/
4. Log out.

This worked. I summarized here from [received wisdom](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5914340?answerId=30724608022#30724608022).

Comment: This assumes that you have a backup. If you don’t, what do you do?