# Restore Messages using Time Machine (not iCloud synced)

Tags: time-machine, messages, big-sur

I've made a stupid misclick and deleted 4 years worth of Messages conversation with my significant other. They're not synced to iCloud, but I do have a recent Time Machine backup. I thought I could restore it from there, and I followed older how-to's (older because they are about iMessages, and I am using Messages on Big Sur).

What I've tried:

1. close Messages
2. restore the whole `Library/Messages` folder from Time Machine
3. reopen Messages

Not only did it not work, but it screwed up *absolutely all* conversations as well. Now, every time I click on a contact's conversation, it disappears. It's like they're in cache, but it can't find them in the database when it tries to load them in full.

So: how do I restore my Messages database from a Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've tried a few different things, and I've got something that works. There are two key points:

1. You need to restore the whole `Library/Messages` folder (not just `chat.db`, as is said in most how-to's)
2. Before you do this, you need to close Message. But also, *after* you restore, you need to reboot the Mac.

Doing all of these things (close, restore whole folder, reboot) means that when you restart and open Messages, your backed-up version is present and functional.

*Phew!*

Comment: You got lucky - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173641/85275 I'll have to try your method if it evern happens again ;)