# How can I transfer text conversations from my Mac to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I accidentally deleted a text conversation off my iPhone, but still have the messages on my Mac. Is there any way I can transfer the text conversation from my Mac to my iPhone? I don't have it backed up on iCloud/iTunes which is why that's not an option.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173640/how-to-re-open-a-messages-conversation